# an example that property $\delta$ does not imply property $\gamma$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641%2882%2990065-7) article, two properties are mentioned at page 153:

**property $\gamma$:** If $\mathcal U$ is an open $\omega$-cover of $X$, then there is a sequence $G_n \in \mathcal U$, with $\underline {Lim} G_n = X$.

**property $\delta$:** If $\mathcal U$ is an open $\omega$-cover of $X$, then, $X \in L(\mathcal U)$

My question is: Can anyone think of a topological space $X$ which satisfies property $\delta$ and does not satisfy property $\gamma$?

Thank you!

**Remarks:**
1. If $\langle A_n : n \in \omega  \rangle$ is a sequence of subsets of a set $X$, 
$$ \underline{Lim} A_n = \{ x \in X : \exists n_0 \in \omega \forall n \geq n_0, x \in A_n \} $$
If $\mathcal A$ is a family of subsets of a set $X$, then, $L(\mathcal A)$ denotes the smallest family of subsets of $X$ containing $\mathcal A$ and closed under $\underline{Lim}$.

2.An open cover $\mathcal U$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called an **$\omega$-cover** if $X \notin U$ and for every finite set $K \subset X$, there is a set $U \in \mathcal U$ such that $K \subset U$.

Comment: This might very well _still_ be an open problem. The paper indicates that R. Laver showed that it is consistent that $(\delta) \Rightarrow (\gamma)$ (by producing a model in which all sets of reals satisfying $(\delta)$ are countable). The paper also poses the problem of whether or not $(\delta) \Rightarrow (\gamma)$ is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. I am uncertain what the status of this problem is.

Comment: I see.. ok. interesting to know. Thank you!!